# How to say that there is a poster located on the wall of my room?

Tags: grammar, meaning

How to say that there is a poster located on the wall of my room ?

How to say that ?

By the way , Is "on the wall" correct ? what about room , in or on ?

Comment: "There's a poster on my wall."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posters hang **on** the wall. You got that right.

As for where that particular wall is, you can use either "of" or "in":

> There is a poster **on** the wall **of** my room.
>   There is a poster **on** the wall **in** my room.

Sometimes there's a "right" preposition to use, and sometimes more than one can be used and the meaning of the sentence doesn't change. You've given a sentence where there's an obvious choice for the first preposition, but wiggle room with regards to the second.

Yes, we hang posters "on the wall", although I can see how a beginner might be unsure of that. See meaning 1c at [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/on):

> touching, sticking to, or hanging from a surface or object
>   *There were several interesting posters on the wall*.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest changing "of" to "in." Also, adding "located" is valid, but unnecessary.

> There is a poster on the wall in my room

Comment: you mean " on" ?

Comment: The sentence I'm suggesting is "there is a poster on the wall in my room."

Comment: That's a valid change, but it's not a necessary change by any means.

Answer (score 1):

Not very specific

> There is a poster on the wall.

Not specific about where in the room:

> There is a poster in my room. (It could be on the wall, or in the closet, etc)

Most specific:

> There is a poster on my [bedroom/bathroom/living room] wall.
>
> There is a poster on the wall in my room.
>
> There is a poster on the wall of my room.

In English, yes, you should use the preposition "on" when hanging things "on" walls.
Things don't go "in" the wall, unless they're actually encased in it, like water pipes or electrical wires, or perhaps a safe that's actually embedded "in" the wall.

You'd use "in" for "in the room" because it is a space you can go "in"to.
You can't go "on" a room (unless you're standing on top of it, and even then it sounds weird).

Comment: I think "on the wall **of** my room" is equally valid, correct, and grammatical. [I'm not alone in this regard](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+wall+in+my+room%2Cthe+wall+of+my+room&year_start=1935&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3)

Comment: Grammatical, valid, correct - yes, to all of the above. Perhaps it's a regional difference? I'd personally never say that. Flip it around and it's like saying "on my room's wall" which is odd since I don't think of the room as possessing the walls so much as being enclosed by them. In that case "in the room" is a better fit for my conceptual model of what a room is :)

Answer (score 1):

You *can* say:

> There is a poster located on the wall of my room.

and 99% of native speakers will know what you mean. If your goal is to be able to communicate your ideas in English, that sentence might be all you want. If you want to use more natural English, you could say

**There is a poster hanging on the wall of my room.**

which is close to your sentence in construction.